# elasticsearch query for groupby with conditionals giving unexpected results

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

I'm using elasticsearch 1.3 and I'm trying to get a groupby on each kind of buisness_process with the counts. Also if I can break that down even further by timestamp would be great.

```
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "should": [
                {
                    "match": {
                        "business_process": "overlimit"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "match": {
                        "business_process": "proposal"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "match": {
                        "business_process": "overdraft"
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    },
    "facets": {
        "name_your_facet_here": {
            "terms": {
                "field": "business_process",
                "size": 100000
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your incomplete question, 
**to get counts of `business_process` of values `["overlimit", "proposal", "overdraft"]`**,

```
POST http://localhost:9200/gccount/Customer/_search
{
    "size": 0, 
    "query": {
        "terms": {
           "business_process": [ "overlimit", "proposal", "overdraft"]
        }
    },
    "facets": {
        "name_your_facet_here": {
            "terms": {
                "field": "business_process",
                "size": 100000
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**or**

```
POST http://localhost:9200/gccount/Customer/_search
{
   "size": 0,
   "query": {
      "filtered": {
         "query": {
            "match_all": {}
         },
         "filter": {
            "terms": {
               "business_process": [ "proposal", "overlimit", "overdraft"]
            }
         }
      }
   },
   "facets": {
      "name_your_facet_here": {
         "terms": {
            "field": "business_process",
            "size": 100000
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Mapping of `business_process` is expected to be `"index" : "not_analyzed"`.

Your current query seems to response only for first match ie `overlimit`.

Comment: This does not work. It's only giving me facets for one type (overlimit) not all the business processes

Comment: @Tazo As I said, Its works fine if your mapping is "index" : "not_analyzed" on `business_process`. Can you update your mapping in question btw.